# how to have two y scales in matplotlib while having a date on x axis

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have the following dataframe :

```
    date       us_dollar    active_user_count
    2016-01-01  4.76        1083
    2016-01-02  46.78       1558
    2016-01-03  60.47       1872
    2016-01-04  218.72      1884
    2016-01-05  78.90       2068
```

need to visualize them in a way that my plot would have two different y scales for each column, i take the following approach :

```
ax=date_usdollar_user[['date','us_dollar']].set_index('date').plot(figsize=(30, 20) ,linewidth=5);plt.xticks(rotation='vertical')
ax2 = ax.twinx()
ax2.plot(ax.get_xticks(),date_usdollar_user[['date','active_user_count']].set_index('date'),marker='o',linewidth=5)
ax.tick_params(labelsize=20)
ax2.tick_params(labelsize=20)

plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

but i receive the following error :

```
x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (13,) and (366, 1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not every datapoint in your plot has its own ticklabel. Here you have 13 ticklabels, but 366 datapoints, hence the error.

If you have a dataframe `df` with three columns `x`,`y`,`z`, you can plot it two twin axes via

```
ax=df[['x','y']].set_index('x').plot()
ax2 = ax.twinx()
df[['x','z']].set_index('x').plot(ax=ax2)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you generally want to plot two columns with different axes then you can also do the following:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
rc_fonts = {"text.usetex": True, "font.size": 30, 'mathtext.default': 'regular', 'axes.titlesize': 33, "axes.labelsize": 33, "legend.fontsize": 30, "xtick.labelsize": 30, "ytick.labelsize": 30, 'figure.titlesize': 33, 'figure.figsize': (15, 9.3), 'text.latex.preamble': [
    r'\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,bm,physics,lmodern}'], "font.family": "serif", "font.serif": "computer modern roman", }
mpl.rcParams.update(rc_fonts)
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(zip(range(10), range(10)[::-1], [pd.datetime(year=2017, month=1, day=i) for i in range(1,11)]), columns=['y1', 'y2', 'date'])

plt.clf()
fig = plt.gcf()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax1.plot(df['date'], df['y1'], 'ko:', label='$y_1$')
ax1.set_xlabel('Date', labelpad=5)
ax1.set_ylabel('$y_1$')
ax1.set_title('Two $y$-axes', y=1.02)
ax1.legend(loc=(0.1, 0.5), handlelength=3, handletextpad=0.1, frameon=False, numpoints=1)
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax2.plot(df['date'], df['y2'], 'r^--', label='$y_2$')
ax2.set_ylabel('$y_2$')
ax2.legend(loc=(0.1, 0.4), handlelength=3, handletextpad=0.1, frameon=False, numpoints=1)
plt.gca().xaxis.set_minor_locator(mdates.DayLocator())
plt.gca().xaxis.set_minor_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%a\n%d-%m'))
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.DayLocator())
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter(''))
ax1.xaxis.set_tick_params(which='both', pad=20)
plt.savefig('example.pdf', format='pdf', bbox_inches='tight')
```

which produces:

[image]